# Vue Animation inside the div element doesn't work

Tags: vue.js

I tried the example

```
<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-show="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
</div>
```

It works!
But when I replaced the Element p with div,it doesn't work!

```
<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <div v-show="show">hello</div>
  </transition>
</div>
```

why Vue Animation inside the div element doesn't work

Comment: Where is your CSS that defines the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Add the css

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
 }
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active in <2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0
}
```